# Visual Studio - SQL Database Project - DacPac stored procedure formatting

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014, database-project, dacpac

I have a VS2015 database project in TFS source control and I am deploying it to SQL Server 2014 as a DacPac. When it is deployed, the stored procedures get reformatted to some kind of default formatting which is less readable than my convention, and which is hard to quickly diff against what is in source control.

Does anyone know of a way to preserve my formatting during deployment, or alternatively to somehow making comparisons easier? (Only solution I see is to make source control formatting match this DacPac default formatting)

Comment: I'm trying to track this down too. An example of what I'm seeing is a column with a default of `GETDATE()` is published as `getdate()`. When I then run a schema compare this comes back as a difference. I also see changes where I have a calculated field that I've broken into separate lines and after publishing it's a single line.

Comment: ...and possibly related -- The default with schema compare is to ignore keyword casing and to ignore whitespace. But turning these options on/off do not seem to make a difference

Comment: I haven't seen that before, but will play around some to see if I can reproduce it. I know that my formatting was always kept in prior releases of SSDT (whether that's good or bad is a different story).

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties for your DB project, there is a "project setting" under "Output Types".  It's a checkbox called "Create script (.sql file)".  If you check this, it outputs a .sql file with a create statement for all your objects that appears to preserve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I typically deploy changes by generating `"Schema Comparison"` (Tools>SQL Server>New Schema Comparison... Project as the source/DB as target), and that always preserves the formatting from the DB Project just fine.  Sometimes I find I need to use the `"Publish"` option instead of schema compare.  Here is an [MSQLTips article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5456/using-advanced-publish-settings-for-visual-studio-database-project/) describing advanced publish options, but I didn't see anything about preserving formatting.  I do not deploy with the DACPAC (I should probably know more about that option). But I know that deploying the schema changes keeps the formatting.